# Accessing Laravel custom Pivot class directly

Tags: laravel, pivot

I'm trying to access a custom pivot class directly through Artisan tinker like this: `App\Registration::all()`. But it seems that classes that extend pivot are not directly accessible?

The Errormessage: Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'teknologiskolen.registration' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `registration` where `registration`.`id` = 1 limit 1)'

Comment: may be you should try ```\App\Registrations::all()```

Comment: Is `Registration` the pivot class? Is there an error?

Comment: Yeah you'll run into missing parameter issues with trying to access anything that extends pivot directly in that way. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir: Yes, `Registration` is the pivot class, and @NMahurin I guess I'll have to access it through the related classes then...

Comment: What's the actual pivot table? You can specify it with `protected $table = '...';`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir. Thank you so much - the DB pivot table is named "registrations", which of course does not match the table referenced in the above error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the table in the pivot model:

```php
class Registration extends Pivot {
    protected $table = 'registrations';
}
```